# Generate random number in a loop and make the loop wait the random number

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to make a small dead chat ping function for my discord bot. The time it sends the ping should be random. I tried this code down here but the interval doesn't wait untill the "wait" is finished and repeats it unlimited times. It there maybe an alternative?

```
 setInterval(function() {
    var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000000) + 5000;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        client.channels.cache.get('933372453009379338').send(`testing ${rating}`)
     }, rating);
}, 1);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep as an alternative for `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `setTimeout` only, and let its callback initiate the next execution of that logic:

```
function loop() {
    var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000000) + 5000;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        client.channels.cache.get('933372453009379338').send(`testing ${rating}`);
        loop();
    }, rating);
}

loop(); // start it
```